# Upgrading the kernel in Redhat Linux 6.0

Tags: kernel, rhel

How do you upgrade the kernel in Redhat Linux 6.0?

And how can I confirm whether it is updated or not?

Comment: Way to go: `apropos kernel` probably mentions `uname (2)`. `man uname` shows you that `uname -rv` gives you the running kernel's release and version.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the kernel is just like updating anything else, e.g. `yum update` should do it (or whatever GUIish front end you prefer). The output should tell you if it got updated or not and `rpm -q kernel` shows you the installed kernels (by default, there should be 3 around for fallback). If it looks OK so far, reboot (the new kernel takes over on reboot). Afterwards, `uname -r` tells you the release of the running kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is available here:
http://www.linuxfunda.com/2013/11/08/how-to-upgrade-the-kernel-on-centos/

While the instructions are for CentOS it should work for Red Hat as well.